# iOS UIButton not loading image when image is assign

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm trying to assign an **"Image"** to **"Button"**, but for reason the **"Image"** doesn't load.

```
    UIImage *bottonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bocinaMute.png"];

    [self.botton.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mute.png"]];
```

When I print it in the console the value of the `imageView` is:

```
po _botton.imageView
<UIImageView: 0x15f53a390; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x170235c20>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
[btnTwo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mute.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

instead of

```
[self.botton.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mute.png"]];
```